# Google Analytics can show which link or div was clicked?

Tags: google-analytics

My website use google analytics and I need to known if is possible monitor which links or divs was clicked by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably be able to use the [Analytics Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide):

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also checkout [Enhanced Link Attribution](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2558867).